# Nodeunit command not found?

Tags: javascript, node.js, command, cygwin, nodeunit

I'm running on Windows 7 and have node installed fine with cygwin.  I am following along on the how to on mcmahon's website for nodeunit: http://caolanmcmahon.com/posts/unit_testing_in_node_js .

I used npm to install nodeunit and it said it had installed fine but when I go to invoke it, nodeunit, it says command not found in all the different directories.

Do I have to set some kind of path variable maybe?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### In Windows 7

You should install your `nodeunit` globally with the `-g` flag

```
npm install nodeunit -g
```

Check your `PATH` by typing the `PATH` command in windows console. If you dont find the `C:\Users\`**`Username`**`\AppData\Roaming\npm;` value, you should check your [environment variables](http://www.itechtalk.com/thread3595.html), and if not containing, add it manually (replace the `Username` to your username).

But I think node installer adds it automatically.

### In XP

The `AppData\Roaming` folder in Windows Vista or Windows 7 is the same as the `Documents and Settings\username\Application Data` folder in Windows XP.
So your variable should look like `C:\Documents and Settings\`**`Username`**`\Application Data\npm;`

Answer (score 7):

Try "npm install -g nodeunit". The -g installs it globally. It's a fairly recent change, so most old documentation doesn't mention it.

Comment: Aaah, that sorted it! I was having a problem with the `vows` command not being found. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

Install the node from official windows installer no need to work with cygwin version in windows. The link is http://nodejs.org/dist/v0.10.12/node-v0.10.12-x86.msi .

Open the command prompt as administrator privilege. Press windows key -> type cmd -> press ctr+shift+enter . This will open the command prompt as administrator. Type npm install -g nodeunit . This will make nodeunit available on the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux you should create a sym link to the binary similar to below (but referencing where your binary is actually installed):

```
sudo ln -s /opt/node-v4.1.0-linux-x64/bin/nodeunit /usr/local/bin/nodeunit
```